# Data loss after android application update

Tags: android, realm, data-loss

I have an android app with 130K users, and Very few users (0-6) reports that their data is got cleared after they updated app from playstore.

I checked the device and found all data in the application data directory is completely cleared even log file. Of course, there is no code that deletes all the files in application data.

I have two questions.

**Q1. Does anyone have the same experience?**

**Q2. Possible reason and any workaround exits?**

In AndroidManifest.xml, `"allowBackup"` is true, and set `"fullBackupContent"` with my rule.
Here is my initialization code.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static KKApp instance = null;
    private Realm _realm;
    private Activity _mainActivity;

    public static void setRealm(Realm realm){
        instance._realm = realm;
    }
    public static Realm getRealm(){
        return instance._realm;
    }

    public static void setMainActivity(Activity activity) { instance._mainActivity = activity; }
    public static Activity getMainActivity() { return instance._mainActivity; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        Realm.init(this);
    }
    ...
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FlickHandler, SimpleCallback, ErrorHandler {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        KKApp.setMainActivity(this);
        openDataBase(FILE_NAME)
    }

    private void openDataBase(String fileName){
        try{
            RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name(fileName)
                    .schemaVersion(Migration.SCHEME_VERSION)
                    .migration(new Migration())
                    .build();
            KKApp.setRealm(Realm.getInstance(config));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            ...
        }
    }
...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you add your realm configuration in Application class?

Comment: I call Realm.init() on Application class and call getInstance() with the configuration on onCreate of MainActivity. Yes, I can move it.  Is this related to this problem?

Comment: do you used deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() ?

Comment: If you add your realm configuration snippet it's will helpful

Comment: No, I never use deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().

Comment: I edit my question and add my code. Thanks.

Comment: is Migration  your custom class? please it also

Comment: FYI : openDataBase is should be in Application class

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try this. 
but I can't understand all files not only realm file but log file and other text file is also cleared. 
Can realm clear entire application data directory?

Comment: no, check your Migration file

Comment: I checked Migration file and couldn't find any code that delete file.